# Have Donetsk and Luhansk recognized each other as independent states?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, embassy

The [Donetsk People's Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donetsk_People%27s_Republic) and the [Luhansk People's Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhansk_People%27s_Republic), fighting alongside Russia against Ukraine, have been [recognized](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2022/07/14/world/north-korea-donetsk-luhansk) as independent states by Russia, Syria, and North Korea (as well as by Abkhazia and South Ossetia, as pointed out in the comments below), but I'm struggling to find any information about the mutual recognition of those two territories as independent states. In particular, I can't find the names of their ambassadors to each other, while I was able to find the [names](https://tass.com/politics/1447913) of their ambassadors to Russia.

I'm highly puzzled by the apparent absence of any information about the mutual recognition of Donetsk and Luhansk, given the ties between the populations of those two territories and them bordering each other and being allies in a military conflict.

Have Donetsk and Luhansk recognized each other as independent states at all? Have they established mutual diplomatic relations? Have they exchanged ambassadors? If not, why? Do they have a problem with each other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They have implicitly recognized each other by being a part of [Novorossia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novorossiya_(confederation)).

When it was suspended, it's quite possible they did not make moves to recognize each other explicitly (both due to [Minsk Accords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minsk_II)?).

Current situation remains unclear and I would be glad to be corrected.

Comment: Good point. As the dissolution of the Novorossia confederation appears to have been less than formal, it's a bit unclear what their mutual status is in the aftermath. On the other hand, Wikipedia says the documents forming  Novorossia  were not fully made public, so we don't know exactly what they signed.

Answer (score 3):

For what's worth it, the DPR (which has a foreign ministry website I could find) doesn't list a representation/embassy in the LPR, although it claims to have one in France etc. (besides Russia)

[image]

The LPR leadership had a somewhat troubled history, with some coups, former PMs dying in their own prisons etc., so it's a bit hard to say how much of the decisions of former administrations had been carried forward by later ones.